# Is JaCoCo by default plugged into SONAR?

Tags: unit-testing, sonarqube, jacoco

Is JaCoCo by default plugged into SONAR?

When I run sonar:sonar, I do see from the logs that a jacoco.exec file is been generated in the /target folder. And SONAR shows me "line coverage" only for this project.

If I don't want to use this default JaCoCo reports and want to replace it with Cobertura, how do I do it? Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed JaCoCo is the default Java coverage engine used by SonarQube. You can install the SonarQube Cobertura plugin to rely on cobertura. Which SonarQube version are you using ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I use SonarQube 4.3.1. When I try to incorporate the cobertura plugin, I could see only the cobertura results on my local workspace, but not on SONAR. In SONAR it shows "-" against code coverage %. Any thoughts on this please?

Answer (score 0):

JaCoCo plugin is not plugged into Sonar by default.

However as per the [Sonar JaCoCo Doc](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/JaCoCo+Plugin) , this plugin is included in the Java Ecosystem.

So all you have to do is get this Java plugin for Sonar - [Sonar Java Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Java+Plugin)

To answer your second question, you can achieve it by doing -
 1. have cobertura sonar plugin included in Sonar
 2. don't include the jacoco plugin in the pom.xml of maven project's  tag. so that jacoco analysis will not trigger in the buidl phase
 3. include the cobertura plugin in the pom.xml of your maven project

Answer (score 0):

You have to :

1. Install the cobertura plugin in SonarQube
2. Configure Sonar in order to use cobertura as the default coverage analysis tool (in 3.7.4 : in General settings > Java > General, set "sonar.java.coveragePlugin" to "cobertura")
3. Run cobertura from Maven (see http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Cobertura+Plugin)
4. Run a SonarQube analysis